# Delete/Prevent trigger on Feed Item

Tags: trigger, feeditem, delete, after-trigger

The initial idea was to block all chatter feed from external batch jobs which run nightly. We had a trigger do it.

```
trigger PreventPost on FeedItem (before insert)
{
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00eo0000000U2if') //User Account Profile ID used for running batch jobs
    {       
        for(feedItem tmp : trigger.new){           
            tmp.addError('API Unable to Post');
        }
    }
}
```

It was simple and very efficient until the scheduled batch jobs ran. The trigger could not prevent the scheduled batch jobs from posting chatter feed into accounts. Upon further investigation, we found out that scheduled batch jobs run as a system and that might be the reason.

Any ideas on if we can delete the feed after it's posted or have a way to prevent it from getting posted?

Comment: My initial thinking is if(!System.isBatch()){} but I don't know think that it would be in the correct context

Answer (score 1):

As @EricSSH mentions in comments, the best way to prevent these chatter feeds from being added in a certain context is to check for that context.

The [`System`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) class has four methods that check various contexts, depending on which kind of classes your org runs, you may need to add one or several.

```
if (
    System.IsBatch()     ||
    System.IsQueryable() || 
    System.IsFuture()    ||
    System.IsScheduled() ||
    UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00eo0000000U2if'
) {
    // Prevent feed item creation...
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you try checking the context variables with a `System.debug` to ensure that your context returned `true`?

Comment: I have tried all four. But I will have System debug to see the context.

Comment: global class PaymentTermBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        recordtype oRecordtype = [select id from recordtype where name   
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }  
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    {logic} THIS IS THE BATCHABLE     global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
      PaymentTermDelBatch b = new PaymentTermDelBatch(); //ur batch class
      database.executebatch(b, 200);
    }
} THIS IS SCHEDULER

Comment: You'd be better off [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/173787/edit) that class into your question, and that looks like a batch job, so if its causing the trigger to run, `System.isBatch` should return true. You should assert that.

Comment: accept
trigger PreventPost on FeedItem (before insert) {

if (
System.IsBatch()     ||
    UserInfo.getProfileId() == '00eo0000000U2if')

{

    for(feedItem tmp : trigger.new){
            tmp.addError('API Unable to Post');
        }
    }
}
did this...